# Issue caused by bytebuddy AgentBuilder$Transformer API changes

Tags: java, maven-surefire-plugin, instrumentation

I am using bytebuddy to instrument method calls in tests. I am running into this issue:

*Agent Error: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class nz.ac.wgtn.nullannoinference.agent.NullLoggerAgent$4 does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract transform(Lnet/bytebuddy/dynamic/DynamicType$Builder;Lnet/bytebuddy/description/type/TypeDescription;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Lnet/bytebuddy/utility/JavaModule;Ljava/security/ProtectionDomain;)Lnet/bytebuddy/dynamic/DynamicType$Builder; of interface net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Transformer.*

The critical issue is the last parameter of `AgentBuilder$Transformer::transform` of type `ProtectionDomain`. In version 1.10.20 this is abscent. I could upgrade but this does not solve my issue as I cannot control the version of bytebuddy being used as many of the programs I want to instrument already have a bytebuddy dependency through mockito, often a slightly older version.

Perhaps shading could work. Any advise how to proceed here ? I could always write multiple versions of the agent for different versions of bytebuddy but this seems very clumsy, and a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured it out -- actually it is rather easy, I am so used to lambdas that I did not see the obvious. This seems to work:

```
new AgentBuilder.Default()
..
.transform(
   new AgentBuilder.Transformer() {
      public DynamicType.Builder<?> transform(DynamicType.Builder<?> builder, TypeDescription typeDescription, ClassLoader classLoader, JavaModule javaModule) {
         return builder.visit(NullChecks.MethodWithoutReturnValues.VISITOR);
      }
      public DynamicType.Builder<?> transform(DynamicType.Builder<?> builder, TypeDescription typeDescription, ClassLoader classLoader, JavaModule javaModule,ProtectionDomain pd) {
         return builder.visit(NullChecks.MethodWithoutReturnValues.VISITOR);
      }
   }
)
```

I.e. just overload `transform` to support the two API versions.